# Discrete Series representations for $SL_{2}$ over $p$-adic field.

Tags: local-fields, p-adic-groups, rt.representation-theory

I am working on the chamber homology for $SL(2,F)$, and stuck at some basic stuff on D.S. reps of $SL(2,F)$.

Let $ I=\left(
       \begin{array}{cc}
         \mathcal{O}_{F} & \mathcal{O}_{F} \\
         \varpi_{\mathbb{F}}\mathcal{O}_{F} & \mathcal{O}_{F}\\
        \end{array}
     \right)\cap SL(2, F)$. Now, let $ w_{0}= \left(
       \begin{array}{cc}
         0 & -1 \\
         1 & 0 \\
        \end{array}
     \right)$ and $ w_{1}= \left(
       \begin{array}{cc}
         0 & -\varpi^{-1}_{F} \\
         \varpi_{F} & 0 \\
        \end{array}
     \right)$, then $J_{0}=I \cup Iw_{0}I$ and $J_{1}= I \cup Iw_{1}I$ are the two maximal compact subgroups of $SL(2,F)$ where $\varpi_{\mathbb{F}}$ is the uniformizer.

Just wondering if anybody knows how can I induce a cuspidal reps(D.S.) from a charachter belong to $J_{0}$ or/and $J_{1}$?

Comment: 1. The definitions of $J_0$ and $J_1$ look weird: shouldn't $$J_0=SL(2,\mathcal{O}) \textrm{ and } J_1=(w J_0 w^{-1})\cap SL(2,\mathcal{O})?$$

2. The question is unclear: are you asking whether a d.s. representation of $SL(2,F)$ can be induced from a character of $J_i, i=0,1?$  

Comment: No mate its as above

$J_{0}=\left(
             \begin{array}{cc}
               \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{F}} & \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{F}} \\
               \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{F}} & \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{F}} \\
             \end{array}
           \right)\cap SL(2)$, $J_{1}=\left(
             \begin{array}{cc}
               \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{F}}& \varpi_{\mathbb{F}}^{-1}\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{F}} \\
                \varpi_{\mathbb{F}} \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{F}}& \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{F}} \\
              \end{array}
             \right)\cap SL(2)$. i.e.$J_{1}=wJ_{0}w^{-1}$.

Comment: 2- Yes, I am asking if a d.s. representation of $SL(2,F)$ can be induced from a character of $J_{i},i=0,1$  and How? 

Comment: w is not elt of (finite) weyl gp. please remove extraneous tags.

Comment: If the question is whether discrete-series representations can be induced from 1-dim. characters, then the answer is no.  If ‘characters’ allows high dimension, then all so called depth-0 supercuspidals arise this way, as in Paul Garrett's answer.  Positive-depth supercuspidals and the Steinberg representation do not arise in this way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inducing a "cuspidal" repn from SL(2,o) produces a finite sum of supercuspidals of SL(2,F). The easiest "cuspidal" repns of SL(2,o) are the ones that factor through SL(2,k), where k is the residue field. The "cuspidal" repns of SL(2,k) can be quasi-explicitly produced via the finite-field version of the Weil/theta pairing, inducing non-trivial characters from a k-not-split $O(2)$ (corresponding to the unique quadratic extension of $k$). Even a simple counting procedure easily shows that induced repns cannot account for all the irreducibles of SL(2,k), so we know that "cuspidal" ones must be there. The Weil/theta correspondence trick happens to produce them.

This kind of discussion already appeared a long time ago, I think in Jacquet's 1970 Montecatini lectures. In more recent times, work of Kutzko et al classifies supercuspidals of GL(n).

Comment: I think the genesis of this construction is in Joseph Shalika's thesis, republished in his birthday volume in 2004. 

Comment: The construction described above (together with the similar construction for $J_1$) produces all of the so-called depth zero supercuspidal representations of SL(2, F). There is a nice complete treatment of this example in Joseph Rabinoff's notes: http://math.stanford.edu/~rabinoff/misc/building.pdf